Find the minimizer solution of $\|A-BQ \|$ using Von Neumann's trace inequality
The questions is:
Let $A,B \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be given. Use the von Neumann trace inequality to determine the solution to the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\min_{Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} \|A-BQ \|^2_F \\
\text{s.t. } Q^TQ = I
\end{equation}
To solve this problem, I think the main idea is to derive a lower bound using von Neumann trace inequality at first, and then construct a Q such that the lower bound is attainable. In practice, I derive the lower bound which is $\|\sigma(A)-\sigma(B)\|^2_2$ but couldn't find a Q to attain that.
Could anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks so much!!!

To begin with, express the objective function in a form to which von Neumann’s trace inequality can be applied.

Sure, $||A-BQ||^2_F = ||\sigma(A)||^2_2 -2trace(A^TBQ)+||\sigma(B)||^2_2$, I believe the von Neumann's trace inequality should be applied on the term $trace(A^TBQ)$.

now write $A^TB$ in (a choice of) Polar Decomposition
